# Job Scheduler Not recurring in periodic in Android 7.0 (Nougat)

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Job is not firing on given time...it delays ...delays...delay time increases. my requirement is to perform job no matter what in every 10 mins using Job Scheduler in Android 7.0 and above.
here my code snippet

```
private static long Scheduler_Interval = 5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;

JobScheduler mJobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

            JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(), JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                builder.setPeriodic(Scheduler_Interval, 1 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            }
            builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);

            if (mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) <= 0) {
                ShowToast("Some error while scheduling the job");
            }


public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {
 @Override
  public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
      writeToTestLogFile(GetSavedDateFromLocationProvider()+ "|onStartJob");
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
      writeToTestLogFile(GetSavedDateFromLocationProvider()+ "|onStopJob");
     return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this functionality on Android 7.0

Comment: With Doze mode on Android 6.0+, the only way that you can do something this frequently is if the user adds your app to the battery optimization whitelist. Not every user will do this.

Comment: @CommonsWare In 6.0 it works fine..but in 7.0 it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

in Android N (Nougat) minimum period interval is 15 minutes . Set your interval to 15 minutes then the code will work.

And also set

```
jobFinished(parameters, false);
```

Comment: Do we need to call jobFinished(parameters, false); for Periodic Tasks as well?

Comment: @ShishirShetty yes

Comment: Aaah bug not. Found it in the code.
    
    `/* Minimum interval for a periodic job, in milliseconds. */
    private static final long MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000L;   // 15 minutes`.

Anyway this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The JobScheduler is optimized by the Android OS, therefor your job never will be executed at the **exact** interval you specified.

> Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval, not more than once per period. You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long)

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I guess with AlarmManager you can register an exact interval

Comment: Alarm manager is also not working in Deep sleep mode...in Android 7.0 instead of Alarm Manager there is Job Scheduler...https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html