# Periodic Job in Android N (Nougat, 7.0)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-7.0-nougat

Okay so I am not able to find any documentation or useful web pages about this.  Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Okay so originally my JobScheduler looks like this:

```
JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
if(scheduler.getPendingJob(JOB_NUMBER) == null) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_NUMBER, componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(60 * 60 * 1000L, 5 * 60 *1000)
            .build();
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service is not running, Job " + String.valueOf(JOB_NUMBER) + " Scheduled.");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service is not running, However job scheduling failed.");
    }
} else{
    Log.d(TAG, "Service is already scheduled.");
}
```

...Works perfectly in Oreo (v8.0).  However in Nougat, v7.0, The job gets 'scheduled' but never run.  In another stackoverflow question I asked I found out that i can get it run by replacing `setPeriodic()` with the following:

```
.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000)
.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000)
```

And with that, the service runs.  However, this isn't periodically, it will only run once.  I cannot find documentation / tutorials / examples that allow me to run a periodic job in Android Nougat.  Can anyone help me with this?

There are other stackoverflow questions on this exact same subject:

[Job Scheduler not running on Android N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344220/job-scheduler-not-running-on-android-n)

[Job Scheduler Not recurring in periodic in Android 7.0 (Nougat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736914/job-scheduler-not-recurring-in-periodic-in-android-7-0-nougat)

However neither of them have definitive answers.

Last minute note: Well, it seems that passing the FlexMillis to `setPeriodic()` seemed to work.  I'm going to do more testing.  I'm not sure what code I was running when the logcat fired, but I think by passing:

`.setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000, 5 * 60 *1000)`

Into `setPeriodic` it fired 10 minutes after the job was scheduled.  However, unlike Oreo, the job isnt run when its first scheduled.  In Oreo as soon as I build the job, the job is run.  Again, I can't find this mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this without refactoring and using the new Workmanager?

Comment: @ArielVardi No.  And actually the Workmanager worked perfectly.  Is there a reason you dont want to use that?

Comment: no reason other than it'd require a larger refactoring, testing, etc. But I guess I go that route if setPeriodic just doesn't do what it's supposed to do on Android N

Comment: Well if its any consolation it was surprisingly easy to transition. Scheduling the job is very similar and instead of a service you use a worker.

Comment: Thanks, @Chud37 - I did end up switching over and so far so good. It was indeed a trivial code change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/. This is new Android tool and it uses JobScheduler/AlarmManager and so on depending on situation.

Comment: Thanks.  Why I hadn't found out about this before I dont know.  But that seems to be the fix for both versions - It works just the same now.  The only difference was i had to use a `Worker` instead of a `Service`.  And actually scheduling it was a lot simpler too.

Comment: I was glad to help you.

Comment: @TT_W can i have sample example.